# How to accelerate numpy array masking?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, numpy, masking

I am profiling performance of a piece of Python code, using a [line profiler](https://pypi.org/project/line-profiler/).

In the code, I have a numpy array `tt` of shape (106906,) and dtype=`int64`. With the help of the profiler, I find that the the second line below `mask[tt]=True` is quite slow. Is there anyway to accelerate it? I am on Python 3 if that matters.

```
   mask = np.zeros(100000, dtype='bool')
   mask[tt] = True
```

Comment: You can try Numba:
https://numba.pydata.org/

It has numpy support, might be worth checking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Numba as @orlevii has suggested:

```
from numba import njit
@njit
def f(mask,tt):
    mask[tt] = True
#Test:
mask = np.zeros(1000000, dtype='bool')
tt = np.random.randint(0,1000000,106906)
f(mask,tt)
```

A simple `%%timeit` check suggests that you should expect roughly 3 times faster execution.

Further speed-up can be achieved by utilizing the GPU. An example of how to do it with PyTorch:

```
import torch
mask = torch.zeros(1000000).type(torch.cuda.FloatTensor)
tt = torch.randint(0,1000000,torch.Size([106906])).type(torch.cuda.LongTensor)
mask[tt] =  True
```

Note that here we use a `torch.Tensor` object which is the equivalent of `numpy.ndarray` in PyTorch. Code will run only if you have a GPU (of NVIDIA) with CUDA. Expect x30 speed-up w.r.t your original code on Tesla V100-SXM2.

Comment: Thank you! Could using Cython make it even more faster? I actually wish to have a 1000X speed up, because my data is too huge (coming from image processing).

Comment: My pleasure! I highly doubt that Cython will provide further improvement in this case. This is a classic case for Numba. If you have a GPU you could have much better speed up using either Numba CUDA or PyTorch/Tensorflow.

Comment: Good to know! How much improvement would you get if you use GPU? You said "much better". Do you happen to have experience on that? Sounds exciting. BTW, what can PyTorch/Tensorflow help there? Aren't they just two libraries for Machine Learning?

Comment: Just read https://medium.com/walmartglobaltech/how-gpu-computing-literally-saved-me-at-work-fc1dc70f48b6. But a silly question, how do I know if I have GPU available? If am using an Mac Book Pro if that matter.

Comment: @zell Yeah I have some experience with optimizing codes on GPU. PyTorch and Tensorflow allow you to utilize the power of GPU/CUDA (not restricted to ML, but built for ML). You can run an equivalent code on a GPU and obtain major speed-up. I ran an equivalent code using PyTorch on Tesla V100-SXM2 (GPU) and I could further speed-up your code by an order of magnitude. This means x30 speed-up w.r.t your original code. See the code I added above. Note that you will need one of NVIDIA's GPUs with CUDA to do this. If you don't have a GPU, you may try using Google Colab.